# how to convert english date format to german date format in php

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

Hi I have a date format like this

(in English format)

```
 15. July 2011
```

And I want to convert it in German format like this

```
15. Juli 2011
```

How to convert date format from one laguage to other language format?

My Code is

```
 $date = '15. July 2011';
 $newLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE');
 $date = strftime('%d. %B %Y',$date);
```

But this is not converting I am getting `July` rather than `Juli`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use [`setlocale`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php) function before calling `date` function:

```
$newLocale = setlocale(LC_TIME, 'de_DE', 'de_DE.UTF-8');
```

**EDIT:** Quote from [`strftime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) docs:

> This example will work if you have the respective locales installed in your system.

Comment: strftime 2nd argument should be timestamp, not string.

Comment: If you have encoding issues: On our CentOS setup the encoding locale must be `de_DE.UTF8`, not `de_DE.UTF-8`.

Answer (score 6):

If you have the [Internationalization](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension installed, you can use the [IntlDateFormatter](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.intldateformatter.php) class.

It's really quite powerful and actually displays the date and time in the correct format for the locale you're targeting.

An example, for Germany might be:

```
// create format
$fmt = datefmt_create("de_DE", IntlDateFormatter::FULL, IntlDateFormatter::NONE, 'Europe/Berlin', IntlDateFormatter::GREGORIAN);

// output (using current time)
echo datefmt_format($fmt , time());
```

*Which outputs:*

**Dienstag, 29. November 2011**